# How do I fix a problem with CLT on Big Sur?

Tags: macos, macos-big-sur, xcode-command-line-tools

I am relatively new to coding on Mac so I apologize in advance if the question is too simple. I encounter the following error when executing a code after updating the OS to Bug Sur:

ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk/usr/lib/libm.tbd' for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The code compiles but the does not give an output file. Everything was working perfectly before updating. Following instructions to a somewhat similar question here, I un-installed the CLT and tried to reinstall the 11.5 version but that couldn't be done and the error was the version of Mac is too new. I'd appreciate any help or suggestions on this.

Comment: What has this question have to do with [tag:fortran]?

Comment: I suspect nothing but I just wanted to make it clear that I am using gfortran compiler. After your comment though, just to prevent confusions like this, I removed the fortran tag.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, in my case I just followed the last comment of https://trac.macports.org/ticket/58681

In particular, launching on the terminal:

```
sudo port -v uninstall ld64
sudo port -v install ld64 +ld64_xcode
```

Comment: Sorry for seeing this late! I uninstalled and re-installed macports again and it solved the issue. Apparently, I hadn't "immigrated" to the new OS properly. Thanks for your response though, I really appreciate it