pip install gemelli gives "ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:"
While I am installing gemelli package on a jupyter notebook it gives me this error.
Building wheels for collected packages: iow
  Building wheel for iow (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /Users/binchoi/opt/anaconda3/envs/qiime2-2020.2/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/sf/_m3jncf51zgdm38790_vm2pw0000gn/T/pip-install-lawcsljt/iow_36e72a19603c46aea7c584e7af0f7359/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/sf/_m3jncf51zgdm38790_vm2pw0000gn/T/pip-install-lawcsljt/iow_36e72a19603c46aea7c584e7af0f7359/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/sf/_m3jncf51zgdm38790_vm2pw0000gn/T/pip-wheel-n1jdkwwm
       cwd: /private/var/folders/sf/_m3jncf51zgdm38790_vm2pw0000gn/T/pip-install-lawcsljt/iow_36e72a19603c46aea7c584e7af0f7359/
  Complete output (43 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  make: Entering directory '/private/var/folders/sf/_m3jncf51zgdm38790_vm2pw0000gn/T/pip-install-lawcsljt/iow_36e72a19603c46aea7c584e7af0f7359/bp/BitArray'
  make: 'libbitarr.a' is up to date.
  make: Leaving directory '/private/var/folders/sf/_m3jncf51zgdm38790_vm2pw0000gn/T/pip-install-lawcsljt/iow_36e72a19603c46aea7c584e7af0f7359/bp/BitArray'
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/bp
  copying bp/_version.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/bp
  copying bp/_cli.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/bp
  copying bp/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/bp
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/bp/BitArray
  copying bp/BitArray/bit_array.c -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/bp/BitArray
  copying bp/BitArray/LICENSE -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/bp/BitArray
  copying bp/BitArray/AUTHORS -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/bp/BitArray
  copying bp/BitArray/Makefile -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/bp/BitArray
  copying bp/BitArray/bar.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/bp/BitArray
  copying bp/BitArray/README.md -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/bp/BitArray
  copying bp/BitArray/libbitarr.a -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/bp/BitArray
  copying bp/BitArray/bit_array.o -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/bp/BitArray
  copying bp/BitArray/bit_array.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/bp/BitArray
  copying bp/BitArray/bit_macros.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/bp/BitArray
  UPDATING build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/bp/_version.py
  set build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/bp/_version.py to '1.0.6'
  running build_ext
  building 'bp._bp' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/bp
  x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -DNDEBUG -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem /Users/binchoi/opt/anaconda3/envs/qiime2-2020.2/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -isystem /Users/binchoi/opt/anaconda3/envs/qiime2-2020.2/include -I/private/var/folders/sf/_m3jncf51zgdm38790_vm2pw0000gn/T/pip-install-lawcsljt/iow_36e72a19603c46aea7c584e7af0f7359/bp/BitArray -I/Users/binchoi/opt/anaconda3/envs/qiime2-2020.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/private/var/folders/sf/_m3jncf51zgdm38790_vm2pw0000gn/T/pip-install-lawcsljt/iow_36e72a19603c46aea7c584e7af0f7359/bp/BitArray -I/Users/binchoi/opt/anaconda3/envs/qiime2-2020.2/include/python3.6m -c bp/_bp.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/bp/_bp.o
  In file included from bp/_bp.c:770:
  In file included from /Users/binchoi/opt/anaconda3/envs/qiime2-2020.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4:
  In file included from /Users/binchoi/opt/anaconda3/envs/qiime2-2020.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12:
  In file included from /Users/binchoi/opt/anaconda3/envs/qiime2-2020.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1832:
  /Users/binchoi/opt/anaconda3/envs/qiime2-2020.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with "          "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-W#warnings]
  #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
   ^
  1 warning generated.
  x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-rpath,/Users/binchoi/opt/anaconda3/envs/qiime2-2020.2/lib -L/Users/binchoi/opt/anaconda3/envs/qiime2-2020.2/lib -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-rpath,/Users/binchoi/opt/anaconda3/envs/qiime2-2020.2/lib -L/Users/binchoi/opt/anaconda3/envs/qiime2-2020.2/lib -Wl,-export_dynamic -Wl,-pie -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-dead_strip_dylibs -Wl,-rpath,/Users/binchoi/opt/anaconda3/envs/qiime2-2020.2/lib -L/Users/binchoi/opt/anaconda3/envs/qiime2-2020.2/lib -march=core2 -mtune=haswell -mssse3 -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -O2 -pipe -isystem /Users/binchoi/opt/anaconda3/envs/qiime2-2020.2/include -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -mmacosx-version-min=10.9 -isystem /Users/binchoi/opt/anaconda3/envs/qiime2-2020.2/include -arch x86_64 build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/bp/_bp.o -L/private/var/folders/sf/_m3jncf51zgdm38790_vm2pw0000gn/T/pip-install-lawcsljt/iow_36e72a19603c46aea7c584e7af0f7359/bp/BitArray -lbitarr -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/bp/_bp.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  ld: warning: -pie being ignored. It is only used when linking a main executable
  ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd' for architecture x86_64
  clang-9: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  error: command 'x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for iow
  Running setup.py clean for iow
Failed to build iow
...
...

Could anyone help me out with this problem? I have tried to update pip but does not work and gemelli package does not seem to be in conda.

Try something from https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ld%3A+unsupported+tapi+file+type+%21tapi-tbd+in+YAML+file+for+architecture+x86_64 May be this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66124929/7976758 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/72494493/7976758
